# What is the best way to define/initialize a variable after DOM has loaded in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to create an input range in React. You can drag it left or right and it'll decrease/increase the "sortingSpeed" variable. However, when I try to start my program, I get a compiler error that says "TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null."

Here's my code:

```
var sliderForSortingSpeed = document.getElementById('array-speed-slider');
export let sortingSpeed = 0.1;

function Menubar({newArray, data}) {

    sliderForSortingSpeed.addEventListener("change", function() {
        sortingSpeed = sliderForSortingSpeed;
    })

    return(
        <div id="menubar-container">
            <label className="slider-box">
                <p className="slider-text">Sorting Speed</p>
                <input type="range" min={1} max={1000} className="slider" id="array-speed-slider" />
            </label>
        </div>
    )
```

I believe the error happens because the variable declaration and initialization happens before the DOM is loaded:

```
var sliderForSortingSpeed = document.getElementById('array-speed-slider');
.
.
.
<input type="range" min={1} max={1000} className="slider" id="array-speed-slider" />
```

I thought I could fix this via useEffect such that the initialization of "sliderForSortingSpeed" would happen after the DOM is loaded. And I thought it would work when `console.log(sliderForSortingSpeed);` kept correctly printing "0.1" instead of "undefined".

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";'
var sliderForSortingSpeed; //Declaration here

export let sortingSpeed = 0.1;

function Menubar({newArray, data}) {

    useEffect(() => {
        sliderForSortingSpeed = document.getElementById('array-speed-slider'); // Initialization should happen after DOM loads
        // console.log(sliderForSortingSpeed);
    }, [])

    sliderForSortingSpeed.addEventListener("change", function() { // Still gets null error for addEventListener
        sortingSpeed = sliderForSortingSpeed;
    })

    return(
        <div id="menubar-container">
            <label className="slider-box">
                <p className="slider-text">Sorting Speed</p>
                <input type="range" min={1} max={1000} className="slider" id="array-speed-slider" />
            </label>
        </div>
    )
}
```

However, I still get the same error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null."

Where am I going wrong? Is this even the best way to define/initialize the variable AFTER the DOM has loaded in React?

Comment: Why aren't you using React `onChange`? Not a good practice in react trying to query the dom with methods like `getElementById()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React uses different operating procedures than standard JS + HTML. You should rarely, if ever, use functions like `document.getElementById` when working with React.

The proper way to get the value of an input component is to provide a function for `onChange` when you create the component:

```js
const { useState } = React;

// A slider that displays the value
function Slider({ props }) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(1); // default value of 1
  return (<div>
      <input type="range" min="1" max="1000" value={value} onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)} />
      <p>Value is {value}</p>
    </div>);
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(<Slider />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Answer (score -2):

You are trying to listen DOM elements before the DOM has been loaded.

To use elements after the DOM has been loaded in React functional component you can use `useEffect()`

For exemple :

```
 useEffect(() => {
        var sliderForSortingSpeed = document.getElementById('array-speed-slider');
        console.log(sliderForSortingSpeed)
    }, [])
```

As @charlietfl said

> Not a good practice in react trying to query the dom with methods like getElementById()

Comment: I imagine a setInterval would work about as well as this